# Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS Header missing when uploading large files

Tags: angular, api, nestjs

So, when I try to upload a file to NestJS via Angular and FormData, it works fine with pictures and files that is less than **~1-2 MB**, but when I try to upload a **9 MB** file, the console gives the following error:

> Cross-Origin request blocked: The same-origin policy does not allow reading the remote resource from: MyApiLink. (Cause: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" CORS header is missing). Status code: 413.

Can you tell me why?

Heres my code:

**Main.ts (NestJS):**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors()
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**File upload (NestJS):**

```
  @Post("uploadImg")
  @UseInterceptors(
    AnyFilesInterceptor({
      storage: diskStorage({
        destination: function (req: any, file, cb) {
          console.log(file);


          function mkdirRecursiveSync(path: string) {
            if (!existsSync(path)) {
              mkdirRecursiveSync(dirname(path));
              mkdirSync(path);
            }
          }

          const destPath = `CDN/attachments/${req.body.dest}`;
          mkdirRecursiveSync(destPath);
          console.log(req.body)
          cb(null, destPath);
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          console.log(file)
          cb(null, file.originalname);
        },
      }),
    })
  )
  async uploadedFile(@UploadedFiles() file) {
    console.log(file)
    return file;
  }
```

**File upload (Angular (Removed some code from it)):**

```
          let formData = new FormData()

          let dateX = cur_day + hours + minutes + seconds;

          formData.append("dest", `${this.chatid}/${this.userData.userid}/${dateX}/`)
          this.draftImages.forEach((fileData: any) => {


            formData.append("file", fileData.file, fileData.name)
            console.log(fileData.file);
          })

          console.log(formData)
          this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:3000/chat/message/dm/uploadImg", formData).subscribe((result) => {
            console.log(result, formData)
            let filesUploaded: any = []
            this.draftImages = []

            Array.from(result).forEach((file: any) => {
              filesUploaded.push(file.destination + file.originalname)
            })

            this.dmService.sendMessage({
              message: message,
              chatid: this.chatid,
              userid: this.userData.userid,
              username: this.userData.username,
              pfp: this.userData.pfp,
              files: filesUploaded
            });

          })
}
```

Comment: I have seen the cors error once on network calls that didn't have anything to do with cors. there was an error somewhere in my stream. can you add `(err)=> console.error(err)` to you subscribtion. to see if something happends during upload

Comment: Are you trying this locally on your machine or are you using Nginx for instance ?

Comment: Locally its working. Im currently trying on Nginx yes

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include clarifications made in comments (e.g., adding the nginx tag). Also, read [ask], particularly the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". I've made an attempt, but it should really come from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving an HTTP 413 error (Payload Too Large) because of Nginx default configuration.

To accept larger files you need to add `client_max_body_size` in your configuration file and assign it a value :

```bash
client_max_body_size 4m;
```

As defined in Nginx [documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) :

> [client_max_body_size] sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body. If the size in a request exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers cannot correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables checking of client request body size.

If you're curious about why browsers have trouble displaying this kind of error, I recommend you to read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/360479/why-might-a-413-not-be-flushed-to-the-client-immediately).